# Action with time intervals in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iPhone app,from one of the views I want to print NSLog(@"Refreshed"); in all 1 minute interval.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `NSTimer` like bellow:-

Define NSTimer in your **.h** class

> NSTimer *TimeOfActiveUser;

in **.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

 TimeOfActiveUser = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0  target:self selector:@selector(actionTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)actionTimer
{

   //Print your log

}
```

**IF YOU WISH TO STOP NSTIMER..? SET ANOTHER ACTION LIKE**

```
-(void)stopTimer
{

    [TimeOfActiveUser invalidate];
    TimeOfActiveUser = nil;

}
```

Hope its help's you my Friend.. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSTimer` in `viewDidLoad`

Example

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                      target: self
                      selector:@selector(onTick:)
                      userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: your timer will never repeat since you are saying `repeats:NO` in your function argument..Your function will only executed once..

Answer (score 0):

Use NStimer Method to give Time interval to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 // enable timer after each 2 seconds for scrolling.
    obj = [ATPausableTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(scrollingTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



- (void)scrollingTimer {

    NSLog(@"Refreshed");
}
```